# Grouping and translating nested objects

Tags: javascript, json, html, angularjs, angular-translate

I need to group and translate nested JSON data, for `<select>` control, that I'm receiving from a http service, ideally not touching the data format on client side nor creating helper structures. So controller would contain near-zero logic for this and whole grouping & translation would be on HTML markup side.

Data I'm receiving is an array of multiple `work groups`, where each holds reference to a `service type` it is related to and all of the `work items` the group has. So (simplified) structure is array of:

**Data**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "serviceTypeId": 1
    "works": [{
        "id": 101
    },{
        "id": 102
    }]        
}, ...
```

For each service type, work group and work I'm only receiving the `id` and I need to translate the values on client, according to current locale. Translations are in JSON files where all key-value pairs are structured as `<KEY>.<id>:<translation>`. For example:

**Translations**

```
"WORKGROUP.1" : "Some group",
"WORKGROUP.2" : "Other group",
...
"WORK.101" : "Work number 101
...
```

So I need to combine the `id` with known `key` to get the correct display value.

What I need is a `<select>` control where all possible `work groups` are grouped by `service type`. Selecting a group would then show all related `works`. This is what I currently have.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="selectedGroup" 
        ng-options="'WORKGROUP.' + g.id | translate group by 'SERVICETYPE.' + g.serviceTypeId | translate for g in groups" 
        ng-change="groupChanged()"></select>
...

<span ng-hide="!selectedGroup">
  <label>
    {{ 'WORKS' | translate }} -
    {{ 'SERVICETYPE.' + selectedGroup.serviceTypeId | translate }} - 
    {{ 'WORKGROUP.' + selectedGroup.id | translate }}
    </label>
  <div ng-repeat="work in groupWorks">
      {{ 'WORK.' + work.id | translate }} <br />
  </div>
</span>
```

The above works just fine but it uses the "group" var I have created from raw data (see link to plunkr below). Is there ANY way to get this kind of grouping & translation of items without added logic on controller side?

Here's related plunker with desired outcome: http://plnkr.co/edit/99gVZe

**EDIT:**
Based on amazing insight by @plalx, here's link to what-I-wanted-to-achieve http://plnkr.co/edit/3bMZZs

Comment: What's the issue with `translate for g in rawGroups`?

Comment: @plalx, there's absolutely nothing wrong with `translate for g in rawGroups`. Can you imagine the amount of facepalm right now? I had trouble handling the group/translate of original data since I didn't realize I could use multiple filters on ng-options... went on creating helper object and working with that w/o realizing same logic applies to original data. Updated my question with link to plunk of what I wanted to achieve. Thx :) !

Comment: That happens to everyone ;)